# How can I make imports work in my Python 2.7 directory structure?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, relative-path, python-module

I'm trying to import custom modules and functions into my Python script, and I've tried both relative and absolute imports, but I really can't make it work. I know this question has been asked here many many times, but trying answers to those questions leads me nowhere... Say I've created a file with functions, func.py, that I have in a subdirectory. It contains the functions func1 and func2. I want to import these functions into my main program file, let's call it prog.py. Here's a simplified version of my directory structure:

```
   C:/Project
     __init__.py
            /Demo
                 __init__.py
                 prog.py
            /Functions
                 __init__.py
                 func.py
```

My `__init__.py` files are empty. I've tried to import func1 and func 2 into `prog.py` in different ways, and none of them work. Using `from .Functions.func import func1` (one or two dots) gives me

> ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

No leading dots gives me a "No module named... " error, kind of as expected. I also tried `from Project.Functions.func import func1` and get the same error.

Haven't I defined it as a package by using `__init__.py`? Do I need to write something in these files, or maybe use `__main__.py` somewhere?

I use Windows 7 64-bit, so I run the script in the command prompt using

> python prog.py

when in the "Demo" folder. It would be inconvenient for me to do it otherwise. I tried using flags for the python command and running it at top-level, but it still doesn't work (I'll recreate it to copy the error message here if needed). Since I'm working in Windows, I've tried adding Project and all its subfolders to the Python path environment variable, to no avail. Maybe I could use `sys.path.append` to add every function "manually", but this would not be very practical considering the actual number of files.

I'd appreciate any help as I've been stuck on this for I don't know how long. Sorry for yet another Python 2.7 import question... Hope I've supplied enough information.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are all `func.py` inside the same folder?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There's one `func.py` and it contains the functions func1 and func2.

Answer (score 0):

sys.path.append will address it. I prefer(what you tried) ENV variable PYTHONPATH you can put there where the libs are then python will search for them there as well..

You say you added this but has your shell picked app the change? Do you see the variable set correctly when you do

```
import os
print os.environ
```

?

Comment: If I put `prog.py`directly in the parent folder "Project" and run it from there, it works using `from Demo.func import func1`, but this is not how I'd like my structure to look, as it would mean a lot of files directly in the parent folder. Using the "dot" notation for relative imports causes a "Attempted relative import in non-package" error.

Comment: Also, yes, sorry, the directories are listed when I run that Python command. I'm using Anaconda, if it makes any difference.